# why npm sass compile not running?

Tags: html, css, npm, sass

[image]

I am also doing editing in my code , but `sass-compiler` not showing any error(red lines ) or any compile successfull line(green lines ). What is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

As we are using sass compiler , which is related to `css` opeartions , and i am doing changes in my `html` file , But when I `edit` my any `sass` file then it started to work ,that's it .
[image]